# The method of() is undefined for the type Set

Tags: java, compiler-errors, set

when i'm trying to run this code:

```
Set<Set<Integer>> s1 = Set.of(Set.of(), Set.of(1));
```

i'm getting this error:

```
The method of() is undefined for the type Set
The method of(int) is undefined for the type Set
```

I'm using Java 8. What is wrong? :/

Comment: They were added in Java 9.

Comment: Look [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

Answer (score 5):

These methods were introduced in Java SE 9. See the `@since` in the source code on the API docs. You'll need to upgrade to a current version of Java or use something else, such as `new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(fred, jim, sheila))`.